# vb.net - what to name my refresh (data) method in a usercontrol

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, naming-conventions

I run across this problem every time I create a `UserControl` which displays some data and I need a method that refreshes the data. I like to use simple common names for everything, and follow the principal of least astonishment and have names that are intuitive for others (or me 6 months from now) to understand.

The obvious name for my method would be `Refresh`, but that's already used by the base class.
I don't want to `Override` it, because I don't need to refresh my data every time the base class calls this method. Data refresh and screen refresh are just different functions and I don't think they should be mingled.

I don't want to `Shadow` it either, because I don't want to interfere with it's functioning.

Something I have not learned yet, which to me is interesting, is that if I `Overloads` it, `MyBase.Refresh()` takes me to the **Object Browser**, and `Me.Refresh()` takes me to my method.

```
  Public Overloads Sub Refresh()
    'Code to refresh data
  End Sub
```

`Me.Refresh()` shows up in the **Object Browser** under my class, and the `Refresh` belonging to `Control` shows up under `UserControl`. Interesting as I never noticed that before.

I'm not sure if this avoids a collision with the base class in all cases or not! I mean, what about late binding? Like I say, I'm not even sure how the compiler knows them apart, but I can see that it does.

It seems like a neat trick but it would astonish anyone using my control, right? Would that astonish you?

What name is the standard name for such a function?

**Better yet, is there a list of vb.net method names that are industry standard for basic common operations?**

**Minutia:**

To nit pick, technically, it's not always a `Reload`, because I'm not always re-loading all the data; maybe I'm just incrementally syncing it. `Load` connotes an initial load, not a refresh. `Sync` is more like it, but this is not the first place most people would look in intellisense for this method, I would think. The name itself should not be astonishing. `Update` is ambiguous; who is updating who, i.e., which direction is the update going? `DataBind` is technically incorrect if I'm not actually using data binding or a data source. And any name that ***I*** can think of that fits all these criteria may not be in common use - `RefreshData`, for example. Not to mention, finally, that a one word name would be simpler.

Comment: What's wrong with `RefreshData`?  You're refreshing the data, right?  Why are you looking for a name that's commonly used elsewhere for a custom operation?  That seems to violate the least astonishment principle you're trying to maintain.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's fine, I just wonder what the rest of the community is doing. Refreshing data is so common, I should think there'd be a standard name for it. Maybe that is the standard name. It's probably the best name I've thought of that is not one word.

Comment: Is refreshing data in a user control not some kind of widely used pattern? I thought it was; perhaps I had a bad assumption. All I know is it pops in my stuff over and over. What name(s) have you used in the past for this operation? Or have you never had the need for this operation? I'm always fascinated by how others do things, since I work alone mostly.

Comment: Generally in .NET development I guess it would be called "rebinding" or "rebinding to the data."  But you claim that you're not actually binding to a data source, so that may not be the case.  The industry standard is (or *should be* rather, but all too often isn't) that the method name should convey what the method does.  So I'm really not seeing the problem here.  I can't say if I've ever commonly needed this operation because I don't have any concrete details on the operation in question.

Comment: If I were to recommend any one single resource regarding good naming in general, it would be this: http://www.cleancoders.com/codecast/clean-code-episode-2/show

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with `Rebind`. It does not conflict with `DataBind` in the framework, so it doesn't need to mean I'm using the .Net databinding mechanism. I wish I could mark that comment as answer! It meets all my criteria; I'll use it until I get my hands on a list of method names. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Reload` is not so bad. I think a name reload doesn't have to worry about how it's reloaded (sync vs full load).